# getUserMedia and WEBUSB over the same device Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, usb, getusermedia, webusb

We are developing a project based on Chrome (old USB API now migrating to WEBUSB) and a webcam. The USB Webcam has a button used for taking picture. In MAC and Linux I can show the live video of the webcam using getUserMedia () and on the same time I can use Web USB API to communicate with the device for detecting button press.
The problem is windows. On Windows Chorme can see the USB device as a Webcam accessible from getUserMedia (if I install the usb device original driver) or as USB device accessible form WebUSB (if I replace the original driver with WINUSB) but we are unable to use the two API toghether. This is a problem only on WINDOWS, in Mac or Linux all is working. How can we solve this?

N.B.
To make the javascript USB commands work on linux and OSX I had to replace "interface" with "endpoint" in transfer commands.

Linux lsusb dump:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID a168:0872 AnMo Electronics Corporation 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0xa168 AnMo Electronics Corporation
  idProduct          0x0872 
  bcdDevice           20.01
  iManufacturer           1 ANMO Electronics Corporation
  iProduct                2 Dino-Lite Premier
  iSerial                 3                         
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          509
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               2 Dino-Lite Premier
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              2 Dino-Lite Premier
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength           80
        dwClockFrequency        6.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0 
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x000200a2
          Auto-Exposure Mode
          Focus (Absolute)
          Iris (Absolute)
          Focus, Auto
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 3
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000147f
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          Gamma
          White Balance Temperature
          Power Line Frequency
          White Balance Temperature, Auto
        iProcessing             0 
        bmVideoStandards     0x1d
          None
          PAL - 625/50
          SECAM - 625/50
          NTSC - 625/50
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                29
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {2652215a-8932-5641-894a-5c557cdf9664}
        bNumControl            16
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          3
        bControlSize            4
        bmControls( 0)       0xff
        bmControls( 1)       0xff
        bmControls( 2)       0xff
        bmControls( 3)       0xff
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               9
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
        INTERFACE CLASS:  0f 24 01 02 67 01 82 00 02 01 01 00 01 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  0b 24 06 01 05 00 01 00 00 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 01 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 08 ca 00 00 08 ca 00 60 09 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 02 00 40 01 f0 00 80 00 02 32 80 00 02 32 00 58 02 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 03 00 a0 00 78 00 a0 00 00 8c a0 00 00 8c 00 96 00 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 04 00 00 05 00 04 00 00 19 00 00 00 19 00 00 00 28 00 20 a1 07 00 01 20 a1 07 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 01 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 08 ca 00 00 08 ca 00 60 09 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1b 24 04 02 05 59 55 59 32 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 aa 00 38 9b 71 10 01 00 00 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 01 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 08 ca 00 00 08 ca 00 60 09 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 02 00 40 01 f0 00 80 00 02 32 80 00 02 32 00 58 02 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 03 00 a0 00 78 00 a0 00 00 8c a0 00 00 8c 00 96 00 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 04 00 00 05 00 04 00 00 19 00 00 00 19 00 00 00 28 00 20 a1 07 00 01 20 a1 07 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 01 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 08 ca 00 00 08 ca 00 60 09 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  06 24 0d 00 00 00
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x13fc  3x 1020 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output from `lsusb -v` above I can see that this device has a single function comprised of two USB interfaces. The Interface Association Descriptor (IAD) signals to the host operating system that these two interfaces are related and operating systems like Windows will treat them as a single interface for the purposes of driver binding.

My guess is that on Linux and macOS you are able to communicate with the EP 1 IN endpoint because only interface 1 is claimed by the USB video class (UVC) driver. On Windows, since it considers both interfaces a single entity "function 0", you are unable to claim interface 0 because interface 1 is already claimed as part of function 0.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have edited the question with the dump. To have the project work on Linux and Mac I had to replace "interface" with "endpoint" in transfer commands.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details. I have updated my answer with specifics based on your device.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So there is nothing I can do on windows I guess?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The Windows driver model simply doesn't allow it. You would need the device to provide two separate functions.